# Specifying val in constructor

Tags: scala, class-constructors

In Scala I can write constructors as:

```
class Cons[T](head: T, tail: List[T]) {
...
}
```

or

```
class Cons[T](val head: T, val tail: List[T]) {
...
}
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 4):

Specifying `val` makes the property publically accessible. (This is the default behaviour for `case class` parameters, without requiring `val`.)

See Section 5.3 of the [language spec](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

As the others said, the difference is that `val` will make the values publicly accessible with the exception of case classes that always treat the constructor parameter as a `val`.

Another more subtle difference is that `val` will make a field in the class, meaning that the reference to the parameter value will exist during the object lifetime.

This does not happen by default when you do not specify a `val`, but still can in case that you use the constructor argument in the class body outside of the constructor body. For example, `a` is used in the ctor body, so it won't be lifted into an object field below:

```
class A(a: Int) {
  println(a)
}
```

In the following example, `a` becomes a private field:

```
class A(a: Int) {
  def foo = a
}
```

because it is necessary to have after construction and during the object lifetime to be able to call `foo`.

One more place where this might implicitly happen even without referencing the parameters from the body of the class is when using specialization:

```
class Foo[@spec A](v: A) {
  var value: A = v
}
```

See the bytecode:

```
  public final A v;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
    Signature: #12                          // TA;


  public A value;
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC
    Signature: #12                          // TA;
```

This was tested using `2.10.1` and it is possibly a bug in the specialization implementation.